# PrimeNG - OrderList

Tags: html, resize, primeng

I am using PrimeNG - OrderList but the buttons are too small

How to resize the buttons to make the bigger?

Here is my code

```html
                        <p-orderList [value]="products"  [listStyle]="{'height':'auto'}" header="List of Option Codes"
                                     dragdrop="true">
                            <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
                                <div class="product-item">
                                    <div class="product-list-detail">
                                        <h5 class="p-mb-2">{{product.optionCode}}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-orderList>
```

The buttons are too small
[image: img of the problematic small btns]

Answer (score 1):

You can add css to .product-item like -

```
.product-item {
  font-size: 15px; !important
}
```